# Worklight 6.1.0.1 fixpack failed to install on WAS 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have installed WAS 7.0.0.31 and trying to update WL 6.1.0 to 6.1.0.1 using IBM Installation Manager. WAS processes were stopped.

All IIM steps went fine, and the final step - click the Update button.

It made some progress (see the screen) and stuck.

After some period of time (like 30 minutes) I decided to click Cancel (see the screen) - it did not help.

So, what am I now expected to do? Are there any logs which Worklight post-install script may write, or can I manually run this port-install script?

[image]

P.S. Before this I updated Worklight to 6.1.0.1 for WAS 8.5 Liberty Profile on this machine, which completed fine.

P.P.S. Rebooted, re-tried and left for 1 hour, and it seems successfully completed this time. How can I check fixpack version level for Worklight server? Any property file?

Answer (score 0):

> P.P.S. Rebooted, re-tried and left for 1 hour, and it seems
>   successfully completed this time. How can I check fixpack version
>   level for Worklight server? Any property file?

I do not believe the server holds any "property file" with the version number.
You can check this in 2 ways:

1. You should be able to see this in the IBM Installation Manager, it should list what is already installed... 6101 (for 6101 or 6101+ifix).
2. A bit more involved, but you can deploy a .war, and in Worklight Console you can then click on About, there you will see the server version.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the IBM Installation Manager shows 6.1.0.1. As soon as I deploy something I will check the version via console. BTW, this version comes probably from some JAR file, which can be opened and checked manually?

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't contain a property file with a version.